# Get the id when i drop the columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 columns with multiple rows. Both columns are having 4 rows and it's sortable and draggable. So i want to get the id of first column which row matched with second column which row. A column is LHS and B column is RHS. I can match A column any row with B column any row. I want to get the both ids.

```
<ul>
    <li id="columns1" class="ui-state-highlight">A</li>
</ul>
<ul id="A">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="1">fruits</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="2">flowers</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="3">animals</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="4">birds</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li id="columns2" class="ui-state-highlight">B</li>
</ul>    
<ul id="B">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="5">flowers</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="6">fruits</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="7">birds</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="8">animals</li>
</ul>
```

This code for first column drag and drop

```
$( "#A" ).sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

for example if i drag and drop A column fruits with B column birds,how can i get the both ids?

Comment: What are you using for drag and drop? Got any code you could show us?

Answer (score 2):

Don't depend on your interface to do your logic.
Use two arrays like this

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [5, 6, 7, 8];
```

If you want to get the other column value just do something like this

```
var i = a.indexOf(3);
var value = b[i]; // value = 7
```

Comment: when i change the position of rows ,how can i get the both ids?

Comment: If you change the position of the rows just update your array, and then get the value using the technique I just gave you.